# Populate data with current date only

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have table A that populated every day with data.

And I have another table B that keep historical data from table A.
How can I populate data from table A to table B with current date data only?

thanks,
S

Please advice,
thanks

Comment: Probably my point would be, run population query at 01:00 AM in the morning and populate data for previous date since I need to take whole date data otherwise if I run at 12:30 PM I still have rest of 30 min data left for current date.

Comment: You probably want to look at `MERGE()` to handle this to avoid duplicates and dropping records based on execution time.

Comment: is there a PK defined on tables A and B?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming TableA and TableB have the same structures:

```
Insert Into TableB
 Select * From TableA where YourDateField > (Select MaxDate=max(YourDateField) From TableA)
```

Here we are checking for the max date in TableB so that data does NOT get duplicated

Comment: I believe you wanted to put: Select MaxDate(YourDateField) From TableB, yes?

Comment: to John Cappelletti: I think it should be like that: Select * From TableA where MaxDate(YourDateField) > (Select MaxDate(YourDateField) From TableB), Yes?

Comment: I'm not sure there is MaxDate function in sql server, isn't?

Comment: Yes, you should change that MaxDate from TableB and while this may prevent most duplication, it could miss records @JoeGreen. Can you elaborate on why you are doing this? It kind of defeats 1NF and denormalizes your DB.

Comment: just looking for best way to bring new date data to historical data table.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a SQL server agent job and schedule it to run once a day. The job can run a stored procedure, which populates or copies the data for you.

See these links for more details:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3052/simple-way-to-create-a-sql-server-job-using-tsql/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187910.aspx